# RubyMineで Cannot resolve import into sass/scss file と表示される

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

Macbook AirでRuby on Railsの開発をしております。
[Ruby on Rails チュートリアルの5章](http://railstutorial.jp/chapters/filling_in_the_layout?version=4.2#sec-custom_css)を勉強中ですが、
bootstrap-sassをインストールしてapp/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scssを作成、
`@import "bootstrap";` を追加する部分でエラーが出ています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

チュートリアル通りにしましたが、なんでこのようなエラーが出ているのかわかりません。
原因と解決策を教えて頂きたいんです。

Comment: そのエラーはお使いのエディタが表示しているように見えますが、どのエディタ（もしくはIDE）をお使いでしょうか？もしエディタの問題であれば実行には支障ないかもしれないので、 `rails server` を実行し、ブラウザで正しく表示されるか試してみてください。

Comment: @unarist 返事ありがとうございます。現在、RubyMineで開発しております。rails serverを実行して確認しましたが、一応bootstrapが適用はされているようです。ただ、ちょっとレイアウトが崩れて表示されるので何かエラーのために完全に適用されていないのではないかと思っていますが...

Comment: タイトルからRubyMineを使っているということ、エラーメッセージがわかるようにしてみました。そのエラーとレイアウト崩れは別の問題のような気はしますが・・・。

Answer (score 1):

絶対に直る保証はありませんが、RubyMineのFileメニュー => Invalidate Caches / Restart => Invalidate and Restart とすると、RubyMine側のエラーが解消するかもしれません。

また、unaristさんもコメントされているとおり、レイアウト崩れはRubyMineの警告とは別の問題だと思います。（致命的なエラーであればRailsの画面も表示されないはずです）
まだ解決していなければ、レイアウト崩れはレイアウト崩れとして別途質問を投稿した方が良いと思います。

ちなみに僕もRubyMineを使ってRailsチュートリアルをやったことがありますが、エラーは発生しませんでした。
そのときの動画（スクリーンキャスト）はYouTubeで公開しています。
この動画の中でもcustom.css.scssを作って`@import "bootstrap";`していますが、特にエラーは出ていません。

下の動画の12:30あたりを見てください。

[第5章 Railsチュートリアル第3版・コーディング実況動画 - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tM_tD9eomGk&list=PLEA0slWkH4yGJgO6UEBvLTMFFvp2pZ76I&index=5)

ちょっと時間はかかるかもしれませんが、僕の作ったスクリーンキャストを最初から見ていくと、「しまった、ここが自分の手順と違う！」という箇所が見つかるかもしれません。

スクリーンキャストの詳細については以下のブログをご覧ください。

[「Railsチュートリアル第3版・コーディング実況動画」を作りました - give IT a try](http://blog.jnito.com/entry/2015/04/22/074055)

以上、ご参考までに。